# Spring ModelAttribute to update a form?

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

Can Spring ModelAttribute be used to update a form without a refresh?

I just need something like a controller call via ajax to update the modelAttribute.

Then automated(dynamic) loading/binding data to form.

Or other way just to achieve something like this!

Controller call, update model Attribute, model Attribute, automatic update fields of form.

Something like that.
Or other way that would make it almost automatic dynamic update of form

Comment: The title should not be the start of a question. Please, get a meaningful title and add more details to the body of the question.

Comment: ok? Spring ModelAttribute, can it be used for dynamic binding to a form? no refreshes, just like a controller call via ajax to update the modelAttribute

Comment: or a very other way just to achieve the automation of formdataloading!! thanks

Comment: @Agostino how to get answers....

Comment: Wait and hope. A better question would help too. What are you trying to do exactly? Here's a [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/252472).